# MySQL checksum collision assesment

Tags: mysql, replication, hash, checksum

I am planning to implement a table checksum mechanism to validate that replication has occured between two master to master MySQL server. But before I know that hashing function always carry a collision risk and I would like to assess the risks of a collision scenario happening. Does anyone have any information to share or links to similar assessment.

My opinion is that the checksum of the same table on 2 replicated server we could basically neglect the risk of collision but I want facts to prove my assumption.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/checksum-table.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, MySQL calculate the table checksum with [CRC32 algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check). It's very safe for almost data, but for the probability of the collision, please see [CRC32 Collision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515914/crc32-collision) .

And I also suggest [Percona Toolkit](http://www.percona.com/software/percona-toolkit/). It has a similar tool for comparing tables by checksum.

<s>And I also suggest [Maatkit's solution - mk-table-checksum](http://www.maatkit.org/doc/mk-table-checksum.html).</s> Maatkit had been merged into Percona Toolkit. Thanks @BaronSchwartz.

Comment: This is correct; it uses CRC32. I suggest Percona Toolkit instead of Maatkit. Maatkit is discontinued (merged into Percona Toolkit).