# a document (a buffer of ASCII bytes) which has the CRC32 hash (the gzip variant of CRC32), of 0xbbd1264f

Tags: crc32

so i had a homework to get a document (a buffer of ASCII bytes) which has the CRC32 hash (the gzip variant of CRC32), of 0xbbd1264f and unti now i don't know how to get it so if someone know how to do that please answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[spoof](https://github.com/madler/spoof/) will calculate what bits out of a provided candidate set to invert in order to force the CRC to the desired value.

Answer (score 0):

From your question, I think you mean generating collision for crc32 with your document.

You can find a lot of articles about creating crc32 collisions. For example you can see it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515914/crc32-collision), [here](https://github.com/bediger4000/crc32-file-collision-generator) or [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/crypto/comments/3h6qeh/generating_crc32_collisions/).