# Reversing CRC32

Tags: c#, new-operator, crc32

I found a code to reverse CRC32 but I don't know how it works, because im not that good in programming, I just started. I just want to compare 2 files, the old and the new one, then in the new fix the CRC32 adding 4 bytes at the end of the file, so the 2 files will have the same CRC32. Here is the code, is in C#:

```
public class Crc32
{
    public const uint poly = 0xedb88320;
    public const uint startxor = 0xffffffff;

    static uint[] table = null;
    static uint[] revtable = null;

    public void FixChecksum(byte[] bytes, int length, int fixpos, uint wantcrc)
    {
        if (fixpos + 4 > length) return;

        uint crc = startxor;
        for (int i = 0; i < fixpos; i++) {
            crc = (crc >> 8) ^ table[(crc ^ bytes[i]) & 0xff];
        }

        Array.Copy(BitConverter.GetBytes(crc), 0, bytes, fixpos, 4);

        crc = wantcrc ^ startxor;
        for (int i = length - 1; i >= fixpos; i--) {
            crc = (crc << 8) ^ revtable[crc >> (3 * 8)] ^ bytes[i];
        }

        Array.Copy(BitConverter.GetBytes(crc), 0, bytes, fixpos, 4);
    }

    public Crc32()
    {
        if (Crc32.table == null) {
            uint[] table = new uint[256];
            uint[] revtable = new uint[256];

            uint fwd, rev;
            for (int i = 0; i < table.Length; i++) {
                fwd = (uint)i;
                rev = (uint)(i) << (3 * 8);
                for (int j = 8; j > 0; j--) {
                    if ((fwd & 1) == 1) {
                        fwd = (uint)((fwd >> 1) ^ poly);
                    } else {
                        fwd >>= 1;
                    }

                    if ((rev & 0x80000000) != 0) {
                        rev = ((rev ^ poly) << 1) | 1;
                    } else {
                        rev <<= 1;
                    }
                }
                table[i] = fwd;
                revtable[i] = rev;
            }

            Crc32.table = table;
            Crc32.revtable = revtable;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this?  The purpose of CRC32 is to help identify when files are different.  The only application I can think of is changing a file and trying to pass it off as the original...

Comment: You want to apply an invalid CRC to a file?  Every virus scanner in the world will scream about this.

Comment: Im modding Call of Duty Modern Warfare 3, a video game, so dont worry for the antiviruses, just help me, what I said please.

Comment: So, you told us a story and showed us your code. *What is the question?*

Comment: Eric J: That is unfortunately how crc32 is used, but it is not very well suited for this purpose, as shown by the posted example code.

Comment: And this is where that code is coming from: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1608030/168683

Answer (score 8):

Here's some PHP code that will also do what you're looking for
I spent a great deal of time trying to do this for legitimate purposes
so I hope it helps someone

Functions like this could be used to:

1. always have a single hash that verifies files (e.g. all files of a certain type return a common crc, versioning etc. w/o having a database)
2. modify the way hashes are distributed (e.g. distributed computing key balancing)
3. reverse original 4 bytes of a crc32

To test crc32 strings online you can use:   http://www.lammertbies.nl/comm/info/crc-calculation.html

See  http://www.reversing.be/article.php?story=20061209172953555 from where this was adapted from
as I'm not the original author, the original spent a great deal of time on his essay, and it
helped in no small way

Here's PHP code which can be used to modify a given file as follows:

```
<?php

//Calculate the original file's CRC32
$DesiredCRC32 = hexdec(hash_file('crc32b','originalcleanfile.ext'));

//Calculate the newfile's current CRC
$CurrentIncorrectCRC32 = hexdec(hash_file('crc32b','newupdatedfile.ext'));

//Generate a 4 byte string that, if appended to the newfile will result in the original CRC32
echo modCRC($DesiredCRC32,$CurrentIncorrectCRC32);  

// I should note that the original guy that posted this has some incorrect calcs on his page
// but if you read carefully and understand the math, you can pick up where it's incorrect
// and learn a thing or two (I beleive last time I tested this code it was accurate)

// if you wanted to do something via the CLI you could use something like: 
parse_str(implode('&', array_slice($argv, 1)), $_GET);
// and grab the files w/ 
$file1 =  $_GET['a'];
//... etc.

//then you could run it via something like this: 
//c:\php\php -f somefile.php a=c:\original.txt b=c:\new.txt c=c:\newwithcrc.txt




public static function modCRC($ExistingCRC, $DesiredCRC){

$crc32lookup = array(
0x00000000, 0x77073096, 0xEE0E612C, 0x990951BA, 0x076DC419, 0x706AF48F, 0xE963A535, 0x9E6495A3, 
0x0EDB8832, 0x79DCB8A4, 0xE0D5E91E, 0x97D2D988, 0x09B64C2B, 0x7EB17CBD, 0xE7B82D07, 0x90BF1D91, 
0x1DB71064, 0x6AB020F2, 0xF3B97148, 0x84BE41DE, 0x1ADAD47D, 0x6DDDE4EB, 0xF4D4B551, 0x83D385C7, 
0x136C9856, 0x646BA8C0, 0xFD62F97A, 0x8A65C9EC, 0x14015C4F, 0x63066CD9, 0xFA0F3D63, 0x8D080DF5, 
0x3B6E20C8, 0x4C69105E, 0xD56041E4, 0xA2677172, 0x3C03E4D1, 0x4B04D447, 0xD20D85FD, 0xA50AB56B, 
0x35B5A8FA, 0x42B2986C, 0xDBBBC9D6, 0xACBCF940, 0x32D86CE3, 0x45DF5C75, 0xDCD60DCF, 0xABD13D59, 
0x26D930AC, 0x51DE003A, 0xC8D75180, 0xBFD06116, 0x21B4F4B5, 0x56B3C423, 0xCFBA9599, 0xB8BDA50F, 
0x2802B89E, 0x5F058808, 0xC60CD9B2, 0xB10BE924, 0x2F6F7C87, 0x58684C11, 0xC1611DAB, 0xB6662D3D, 
0x76DC4190, 0x01DB7106, 0x98D220BC, 0xEFD5102A, 0x71B18589, 0x06B6B51F, 0x9FBFE4A5, 0xE8B8D433, 
0x7807C9A2, 0x0F00F934, 0x9609A88E, 0xE10E9818, 0x7F6A0DBB, 0x086D3D2D, 0x91646C97, 0xE6635C01, 
0x6B6B51F4, 0x1C6C6162, 0x856530D8, 0xF262004E, 0x6C0695ED, 0x1B01A57B, 0x8208F4C1, 0xF50FC457, 
0x65B0D9C6, 0x12B7E950, 0x8BBEB8EA, 0xFCB9887C, 0x62DD1DDF, 0x15DA2D49, 0x8CD37CF3, 0xFBD44C65, 
0x4DB26158, 0x3AB551CE, 0xA3BC0074, 0xD4BB30E2, 0x4ADFA541, 0x3DD895D7, 0xA4D1C46D, 0xD3D6F4FB, 
0x4369E96A, 0x346ED9FC, 0xAD678846, 0xDA60B8D0, 0x44042D73, 0x33031DE5, 0xAA0A4C5F, 0xDD0D7CC9, 
0x5005713C, 0x270241AA, 0xBE0B1010, 0xC90C2086, 0x5768B525, 0x206F85B3, 0xB966D409, 0xCE61E49F, 
0x5EDEF90E, 0x29D9C998, 0xB0D09822, 0xC7D7A8B4, 0x59B33D17, 0x2EB40D81, 0xB7BD5C3B, 0xC0BA6CAD, 
0xEDB88320, 0x9ABFB3B6, 0x03B6E20C, 0x74B1D29A, 0xEAD54739, 0x9DD277AF, 0x04DB2615, 0x73DC1683, 
0xE3630B12, 0x94643B84, 0x0D6D6A3E, 0x7A6A5AA8, 0xE40ECF0B, 0x9309FF9D, 0x0A00AE27, 0x7D079EB1, 
0xF00F9344, 0x8708A3D2, 0x1E01F268, 0x6906C2FE, 0xF762575D, 0x806567CB, 0x196C3671, 0x6E6B06E7, 
0xFED41B76, 0x89D32BE0, 0x10DA7A5A, 0x67DD4ACC, 0xF9B9DF6F, 0x8EBEEFF9, 0x17B7BE43, 0x60B08ED5, 
0xD6D6A3E8, 0xA1D1937E, 0x38D8C2C4, 0x4FDFF252, 0xD1BB67F1, 0xA6BC5767, 0x3FB506DD, 0x48B2364B, 
0xD80D2BDA, 0xAF0A1B4C, 0x36034AF6, 0x41047A60, 0xDF60EFC3, 0xA867DF55, 0x316E8EEF, 0x4669BE79, 
0xCB61B38C, 0xBC66831A, 0x256FD2A0, 0x5268E236, 0xCC0C7795, 0xBB0B4703, 0x220216B9, 0x5505262F, 
0xC5BA3BBE, 0xB2BD0B28, 0x2BB45A92, 0x5CB36A04, 0xC2D7FFA7, 0xB5D0CF31, 0x2CD99E8B, 0x5BDEAE1D, 
0x9B64C2B0, 0xEC63F226, 0x756AA39C, 0x026D930A, 0x9C0906A9, 0xEB0E363F, 0x72076785, 0x05005713, 
0x95BF4A82, 0xE2B87A14, 0x7BB12BAE, 0x0CB61B38, 0x92D28E9B, 0xE5D5BE0D, 0x7CDCEFB7, 0x0BDBDF21, 
0x86D3D2D4, 0xF1D4E242, 0x68DDB3F8, 0x1FDA836E, 0x81BE16CD, 0xF6B9265B, 0x6FB077E1, 0x18B74777, 
0x88085AE6, 0xFF0F6A70, 0x66063BCA, 0x11010B5C, 0x8F659EFF, 0xF862AE69, 0x616BFFD3, 0x166CCF45, 
0xA00AE278, 0xD70DD2EE, 0x4E048354, 0x3903B3C2, 0xA7672661, 0xD06016F7, 0x4969474D, 0x3E6E77DB, 
0xAED16A4A, 0xD9D65ADC, 0x40DF0B66, 0x37D83BF0, 0xA9BCAE53, 0xDEBB9EC5, 0x47B2CF7F, 0x30B5FFE9, 
0xBDBDF21C, 0xCABAC28A, 0x53B39330, 0x24B4A3A6, 0xBAD03605, 0xCDD70693, 0x54DE5729, 0x23D967BF, 
0xB3667A2E, 0xC4614AB8, 0x5D681B02, 0x2A6F2B94, 0xB40BBE37, 0xC30C8EA1, 0x5A05DF1B, 0x2D02EF8D
);

//More Description:
//Want to append bytes: X  Y  Z  W 
//Take for register  a3 a2 a1 a0  (a is the 'already calculated' crc for string)
//Note that a3 is the most significant byte and a0 the least.
// f is the wanted new CRC byte string, and xyzw is the modification pad

/*
I'll show it a little different way:
a0 + X                  =(1)  points to  b3 b2 b1 b0  in table
a1 + b0 + Y             =(2)  points to  c3 c2 c1 c0  in table
a2 + b1 + c0 + Z        =(3)  points to  d3 d2 d1 d0  in table
a3 + b2 + c1 + d0 + W   =(4)  points to  e4 e3 e2 e1  in table
     b3 + c2 + d1 + e0  =f0
          c3 + d2 + e1  =f1
               d3 + e2  =f2
                    e3  =f3
    (1)  (2)  (3)  (4)
(figure 4)

This is reversed in the same way as the 16bit version. I shall give an example with real values. For the table values use the CRC-32 table in the appendix.
Take for CRC register before, a3 a2 a1 a0 -> AB CD EF 66
Take for CRC register after, f3 f2 f1 f0 -> 56 33 14 78 (wanted value)
Here we go:

First byte of entries            entry   value
e3=f3                     =56 -> 35h=(4) 56B3C423 for e3 e2 e1 e0
d3=f2+e2      =33+B3      =E6 -> 4Fh=(3) E6635C01 for d3 d2 d1 d0
c3=f1+e1+d2   =14+C4+63   =B3 -> F8h=(2) B3667A2E for c3 c2 c1 c0
b3=f0+e0+d1+c2=78+23+5C+66=61 -> DEh=(1) 616BFFD3 for b3 b2 b1 b0

Now we have all needed values, then
X=(1)+         a0=         DE+66=B8
Y=(2)+      b0+a1=      F8+D3+EF=C4
Z=(3)+   c0+b1+a2=   4F+2E+FF+CD=53
W=(4)+d0+c1+b2+a3=35+01+7A+6B+AB=8E
(final computation)
*/
  $ExistingCRC =  ~$ExistingCRC;
  $DesiredCRC = ~$DesiredCRC;

        //a3a2a1a0
        $a3 = (($ExistingCRC & 0xFF000000) >> 24) & 0x000000FF;
        $a2 = ($ExistingCRC & 0x00FF0000) >> 16;
        $a1 = ($ExistingCRC & 0x0000FF00) >> 8;
        $a0 = ($ExistingCRC & 0x000000FF);      

        //f3f2f1f0
        $f3 = (($DesiredCRC & 0xFF000000) >> 24) & 0x000000FF;
        $f2 = ($DesiredCRC & 0x00FF0000) >> 16;
        $f1 = ($DesiredCRC & 0x0000FF00) >> 8;
        $f0 = ($DesiredCRC & 0x000000FF);
        //echo "Existing CRC:" . dechex($ExistingCRC) . " DesiredCRC:" . dechex($DesiredCRC) . "<BR>";
        //echo "a3:" . dechex($a3) . " a2:" . dechex($a2) . " a1:" . dechex($a1) . " a0:" . dechex($a0) . "<br>";
        //echo "f3:" . dechex($f3) . " f2:" . dechex($f2) . " f1:" . dechex($f1) . " f0:" . dechex($f0) . "<br>";

        //capture e3/e2/e1/e0/(4) values
        for ($i = 0; $i < 256; $i++)
        {    
                if (($crc32lookup[$i] & 0xFF000000  ) == ($DesiredCRC & 0xFF000000)){
                $e3 = (($crc32lookup[$i] & 0xFF000000) >> 24) & 0x000000FF;
                $e2 = ($crc32lookup[$i] & 0x00FF0000) >> 16;
                $e1 = ($crc32lookup[$i] & 0x0000FF00) >> 8;
                $e0 = ($crc32lookup[$i] & 0x000000FF);
                $four = $i; 
                break;
                }
        }
        //echo "e3:" . dechex($e3) . " e2:" . dechex($e2) . " e1:" . dechex($e1) . " e0:" . dechex($e0) . "<br>";

        //$d3=f2+e2      =33+B3      =E6 -> 4Fh=(3) E6635C01 for d3 d2 d1 d0
        $d3 = $f2^$e2;    //lookup $d3 and assign the values for d2/d1/d0/(3)
        for ($i = 0; $i < 256; $i++)
        {       
                if (($crc32lookup[$i] & 0xFF000000  ) == ($d3 << 24)){
                $d2 = ($crc32lookup[$i] & 0x00FF0000) >> 16;
                $d1 = ($crc32lookup[$i] & 0x0000FF00) >> 8;
                $d0 = ($crc32lookup[$i] & 0x000000FF);
                $three = $i; 
                break;
                }
        }
        //echo "d3:" . dechex($d3) . " d2:" . dechex($d2) . " d1:" . dechex($d1) . " d0:" . dechex($d0) . "<br>";
        //c3=f1+e1+d2   =14+C4+63   =B3 -> F8h=(2) B3667A2E for c3 c2 c1 c0
        $c3 = $f1^$e1^$d2;

        for ($i = 0; $i < 256; $i++)
        {   
                if (($crc32lookup[$i] & 0xFF000000  ) == ($c3 << 24)){
                $c2 = ($crc32lookup[$i] & 0x00FF0000) >> 16;
                $c1 = ($crc32lookup[$i] & 0x0000FF00) >> 8;
                $c0 = ($crc32lookup[$i] & 0x000000FF);
                $two = $i; 
                break;
                }
        }
        //echo "c3:" . dechex($c3) . " c2:" . dechex($c2) . " c1:" . dechex($c1) . " c0:" . dechex($c0) . "<br>";
        //b3=f0+e0+d1+c2=78+23+5C+66=61 -> DEh=(1) 616BFFD3 for b3 b2 b1 b0
        $b3 = $f0^$e0^$d1^$c2;
        for  ($i = 0; $i < 256; $i++)
        {   
                if (($crc32lookup[$i] & 0xFF000000  ) == ($b3 << 24)){
                $b2 = ($crc32lookup[$i] & 0x00FF0000) >> 16;
                $b1 = ($crc32lookup[$i] & 0x0000FF00) >> 8;
                $b0 = ($crc32lookup[$i] & 0x000000FF);
                $one = $i;
                break;
                }
        }
        /*
        Now we have all needed values, then
        X=(1)+         a0=         DE+66=B8
        Y=(2)+      b0+a1=      F8+D3+EF=C4
        Z=(3)+   c0+b1+a2=   4F+2E+FF+CD=53
        W=(4)+d0+c1+b2+a3=35+01+7A+6B+AB=8E
        (final computation)
        */
        $X = $one ^ $a0;
        $Y = $two ^ $b0^$a1;
        $Z = $three ^ $c0^$b1^$a2;
        $W = $four ^ $d0 ^ $c1 ^ $b2^$a3;

    //echo "Four:" . dechex($four) . " Three:" .dechex($three)." Two:".dechex($two)."One:" .dechex($one) . "<br>";
    //echo "X:" . dechex($X) . " Y:" . dechex($Y) . " Z:" . dechex($Z) . " W:" . dechex($W) . "<br>";
    return chr($X) .  chr($Y) . chr($Z) . chr($W);
}
?>
```

Comment: Amazing! Working php function to forge crc32 is something that's very hard to find. Too bad that it's posted as an answer to non-php question.

Answer (score 1):

Would you like to know how it works, or how to use it?

If it's the later, than from the code signature:

```
public void FixChecksum(byte[] bytes, int length, int fixpos, uint wantcrc)
```

It seems that you put the contents of your second file to an array (with additional 4 bytes at the end for the fix), and pass it as the `bytes` parameter. You pass the lengths of this array as the `length` parameter, you pass the offset to the place to insert the fix to, (in this case length - 4) as `fixpos` parameter, and you put your desired CRC as `wantcrc` parameter, you can obtain this value, by calculating CRC of the first file.

`FixChecksum` method appears to write the 4 bytes fix in the array you have provided at the offset you have provided. After you've made the call to `FixChecksum` you just need to write the results to your second file.