# obfuscate values in python

Tags: php, python, encoding, hash

Lets say I have the following strings

```
a = "123456"
b = "#$%[{\"
c = "ABCDEFG"
```

I need to convert these three string into a "d" string with the following properties

- The "d" string is obfuscate (it does not need to be encrypted)
- The "d" string can be converted into the a,b,c string (it is reversible)
- The "d" string should be fast to compute
- The "d" string should be as short as possible

So far what I do is something like this

```
d = a+"|"+b+"|"+c
d = base64.encode(d)
```

So far this accomplishes the first three requirements, but not the third one, as base64 tends to make strings pretty big.

I have been also looking at other solutions

- Use XOR encryption
- Consider using CRC32 as some questions ([Reversing CRC32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1514040/reversing-crc32)) states that it might be possible to revert it, however, I am not sure about it.

Finally note that the "obfuscation" part is done by python and the "restoration" part is done by php.

Any ideas?

Comment: Instead of base64-encoding, just add a constant to each character's ordinal value.

Comment: @WaleedKhan Do you mean something like the rot13 encoding?

Comment: Base64 is only 33% larger, is it that big of a deal?

Comment: How obfuscated do you need your strings to be? After `d` is created, you could use the regex `(.)(.)` and replace it with `\2\1`. To reverse, use the exact same regex/replacement. The size of `d` wouldn't change at all.

Comment: @DanielHaley What is that `(.)(.)` ??  It looks like .. you know ... `( . Y . ) ԅ(ˆ⌣ˆԅ)`

Comment: :-) Find two characters and swap them. Example: `This string is now obfuscated.` becomes `hTsis rtni gsin woo fbsuacet.d`. It's not a high level of obfuscation, but might be sufficient for this question?

Comment: @Patashu Yes, it is, specially because the longer the string gets, the bigger than 33% is. In the given example strings are short, but they might grow in other cases.

Answer (score 1):

If your strings are a little longer than your examples, then the [`zlib` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/zlib.html) might be a good fit:

```
>>> import zlib
>>> zlib.compress("123456789123456789")
'x\x9c3426153\xb7\xb04\x841\x00#\x01\x03\xbb'
>>> zlib.decompress(_)
'123456789123456789'
```

However, short strings will tend to get longer due to the format's overhead:

```
>>> zlib.compress("1234")
'x\x9c3426\x01\x00\x01\xf8\x00\xcb'
```

Decompression can be done with PHP's  [`gzuncompress`](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.gzuncompress.php).

Answer (score 1):

You could just do a simple [Caesar Cypher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher):

```
from string import printable as alphabet 
import string

def caesar(plaintext, shift):
    shifted_alphabet = alphabet[shift:] + alphabet[:shift]
    table = string.maketrans(alphabet, shifted_alphabet)
    return plaintext.translate(table)

shift=3
for s in ("123456","#$%[{\\","ABCDEFG"):
    coded=caesar(s,shift)
    print s
    print coded
    print caesar(coded,-shift)
    print
```

Prints:

```
123456
456789
123456

#$%[{\
&'(^~_
#$%[{\

ABCDEFG
DEFGHIJ
ABCDEFG
```

By definition, the strings get no longer or shorter. I have tweaked the code to handle your examples.

Comment: I have tried with rot13 but I discarded it, as it only works for letters, if you see the examples I put, i need to obfuscate not only numbers but also other characters such as #$%^ ...

Comment: @JuanAntonioGomezMoriano: I added support for your examples. Not extensively tested, but it does work with a defined and stable character set like all ascii letters. You may need to limit the end letters though since the translated letter may pick up additional meaning like DEL