# How easy is it to crack a manipulated hash

Tags: security, cryptography

Lets say for example I used a function such as:

```
int someHash(string someValue)
{
    return crc32(someValue) + 10 - 5 * 20;
}
```

How easy would it be to deduce how the hash was manipulated in order to reproduce the same hash value?

Comment: If the original string is greater than four bytes, crc32 it cannot be reverse engineered - only brute forced - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1514040/reversing-crc32

Comment: I think the question is about if hash involves custom manipulation to the hash value.

Comment: @ramailosathi is correct. Assume that the original string/data is known but is not supposed to be changed. data is hashed and hash value is saved along with data.

Comment: In general is not possible. Suppose the change is to compute low32(sha256(0x76123bed ^ crc32(x))). How do you figure that out? Without some limitations on what changes were made it's not do-able.

Answer (score 2):

This depends on the transformation. In the case of your `someHash` function, this is very easy. Notice that the transformation you are applying is an easy linear function. Your transformation can be expressed as:

[image]

Where *h'* is the new hash and *h* is the original hash. If you have one hash and its altered hash, you can solve the equation for *c*. (`c = h' - h = -90`).

This example is one of many, why we often say that [rolling your own crypto](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/18197/152961) is often not a really good idea. The scheme actually needs two properties:

1. The scheme has to generate output that looks [random](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_oracle).
2. The scheme cannot be easily guessed.

The attack mentioned above is *one reason* why **1.** is important. In this case, the transformation has a very clear structure, which we can easily exploit.

**2.** is needed, because even if we did not have a scheme that had this structure, we can still enumerate over `c`. After having tried a really small amount of numbers, we still find the constant `c = -90`.

This does not mean that this is impossible. Quite the contrary: We use a block cipher to re-encrypt the hash. This works, because a block cipher produces an output that looks random and it takes a randomly generated ≥128 bit key, (which is large enough such that it cannot be guessed easily).